# How to link properly in Makefile?

Tags: unix, linker, makefile

This is my makefile:

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -c cpp2html.o lex.yy.o

cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
    gcc -c cpp2html.c

lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l
    flex cppscanner.l

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -c lex.yy.c
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
gcc -c cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
gcc: warning: cpp2html.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: lex.yy.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I am very new to Unix so any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` option to the compiler tells it to compile only and generate a `.o` file.  When you're linking a program you do *not* want to use `-c`.

Since you say you're new to UNIX I'll mention that UNIX has a long history of including documentation with the system; there are reference pages called *man pages* that can be read using the `man` command.  You can, at the command line, run `man gcc` (or `man ls` or whatever) to get a synopsis of how to use a program along with (at least) it's most basic options and what they do.  This is not in-depth documentation but it's handy.  For a complex program like the compiler there is often other additional documentation available; the man page will usually tell you how to access it.

And, for GCC and other similar tools, there is online documentation as well.